# Python using Threading and Async together? Or another solution?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, streaming, python-asyncio

[image: This is what I'm trying to do in python]

This picture is an illustration of what I am trying to do in Python.

1. I need to create a function that streams information and inputs information into a Queue object
2. I need a function that draws in real time items from that queue and determines if they meet my criteria. This needs to run concurrently with the first function
3. When that criteria is met, a new (temporary) process is created using web requests do something online with the item found. Waiting
   for these web requests can take a long time, so this needs to run
   concurrently as well.

I've figured out how to do 1 and 2 together And I've figured out how to do 2 and 3 together. But I'm not sure how to do all 3 at once.

Here's my solution for 1 and 2 using threading:

```
q=Queue()

def fill_queue():
    x=0
    while x<6:
        q.put(x)
        print('fill',x)
        time.sleep(1)
        x=x+1

def empty_queue():
    for job in iter(q.get,None):
        print('empty',job)

fill_queue=Thread(name='fill_queue',target=fill_queue)
empty_queue=Thread(name='empty_queue',target=empty_queue)

fill_queue.start()
empty_queue.start()
```

Here's my solution for 2 and 3 using async:

```
async def empty_queue():
    queue_inputs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    for queue_input in queue_inputs:
        await asyncio.sleep(.5)
        print(queue_input)
        if queue_input==5:
            check_website=asyncio.create_task(open_website())

async def open_website():
    print('start opening website')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('done fetching.')

async def main():
    await empty_queue()

asyncio.run(main())
```

If I try to run these async functions as threads, I get an error. If I could run async functions as threads, it would fix my problem, but I'm not sure that's possible. I'm also open to other creative solutions to this problem, or ones that would be better anyway. The main bottleneck for all these functions is i/o rather than processing power, which is why I favor threading over parallel processing

Comment: I'd use a completely asynchronous approach here. Use an `asyncio.Queue`, create a task (producer) that will put items into it. Create another task (consumer) that will validate the items in the queue and makes the web requests. I'd suggest to use an asynchronous library like [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński how can I run the producer and consumer functions concurrently without threading? For the web requests I'm currently using the "requests" library. Are you suggesting aiohttp as an alternative to that for async programs?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use `requests` within asynchronous code. To run those two functions concurrently you can either make them a task of use `asyncio.gather(consumer(), producer())` to run them both concurrently and wait for completion